# Functional testing: How to keep a backend mock up to date

Tags: testing, frontend, functional-testing

For running functional tests against a front-end, we are considering mocking our backend. 
Our backend iterates quite fast and changes a lot, though. So mocking it would mean we'd always need to be aware of all changes and update our mocks accordingly.

I was wondering if it is possible to automate this process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're going to do is something related to [Consumer Driven Contracts](http://martinfowler.com/articles/consumerDrivenContracts.html)

Some time ago we had a similar need, and we've developed java based tool, which now exists under [Spring Cloud Contract](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/). If you're using a non-java backend you can try [Pact](https://github.com/realestate-com-au/pact) which supports Java as well as other languages, but is harder to incorporate in JVM world. Spring Cloud Contract also supports messaging support (JMS, RabbitMQ, etc).

The main idea is that you're writing the contract of your backend service, and this contract is used to generate two artifacts:

1. mocks for the client side (in your case frontend)
2. tests for the service side (in your case backend)

Then you can incorporate service tests in your delivery pipeline and be sure that your backend is consistent with the mock, which you used to test  the frontend application.

Comment: +1 to Pact: pioneer, mature, multiple language support (including JVM languages) and with a growing community behind.

Comment: @MauriEdo Pact is much heavier compared to Spring Cloud Contract, so if you use only JVM then Spring Cloud is better solution. It also supports messaging (RabbitMQ, JMS, etc)

Comment: Thanks for editing your response, I just wanted to point out that you /can/ use Pact for a JVM based language, given your original response read as if you can't.

Comment: Why? I wrote "supports also other languages" - "also" tells that JVM is supported as well